# Windows desktop icons refreshing after wake-from-sleep

Tags: windows, sleep, desktop-icons

How can I figure out what process is causing my Win 10 desktop icons to redraw/refresh every day?  I sleep my computer every night, and when I wake it up each morning, usually around 2-3 minutes after waking it up, all the desktop icons get redrawn.  I have tried using Task Explorer to see what processes are taking the most CPU time when this happens, but nothing jumps out at me as the obvious culprit.  I see things like Antimalware Service Executable at the top of the list, usually.

Is there a way I can definitively track down the specific process causing the desktop icons to redraw shortly after waking up my computer every morning? This happens only on my desktop PC, not on my laptop which is also running Win 10, so it doesn't seem to be a generic Windows start-up thing.

Comment: Can you fully interact with your computer prior to the icons refreshing? My own computer takes about 10 seconds after resuming from sleep to fully wake up. I can move the mouse, but things like the Start Menu will not open. I don't keep any icons visible on my desktop, but the desktop does flash after those 10 seconds and then I can interact with the computer again. Also, have you checked that you have the latest drivers (especially video)?

Comment: Yes I can interact with it very soon after it wakes up, and I'm usually browsing in Chrome when I notice that all the desktop icons start to refresh.  It seems to happen pretty consistently about 2-4 minutes after I wake the PC up, and at least 2 or 3 minutes after I start interacting with it.  I will check to see if my video drivers are up to date.

Comment: I noticed this morning that the icons all refreshed even thought I did NOT sleep my computer overnight.  It happened about 30 minutes after I started using the computer.  Any ideas for how I figure this out?

Comment: Lots of 'workaround' discussions about this...tried a few but eventually all failed. This problem existed 'back in the day', and brought about the success of Norton Tools ..... well now we have Stardock and they have a product called Fences....on sale now... nice tool ... I use other tools from them and most successful. Cost $19 or so on sale now. Tired of screwing with my ICONs getting reset... Fences solved my problem....not just a workaround ...an app to deal with these annoying/destructive problems from MS!